# Why is my Mac Mini unable to burn CD's using Finder? I'm getting error 0x80020063

Tags: macos, finder, mac-mini, optical-drive, cd-burning

I'm having trouble burning some files to CD's using the finder. Every time I attempt to do so, disc verification hangs at 0%, followed by a bad media error (0x80020063). I've already attempted to use a few dozen CD's, including one from another spindle.

> This disc can’t be verified and might be unreliable. Try again using a new blank disc (error code 0x80020063).

The burner works perfectly when burning audio CDs using iTunes (with the same media). The files in question are only 25 MB.

The Console DiscRecording.Log shows the following:

```
Finder: Burn started, Sat Nov  2 18:20:19 2013
Finder: Burning to CD-R media with SAO strategy in HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GA32N KC08 via ATAPI.
Finder: Requested burn speed was 10x, actual burn speed is 10x.
Finder: Burn underrun protection is supported, and enabled.
Finder: Burn finished, Sat Nov  2 18:21:23 2013
Finder: Verify started, Sat Nov  2 18:21:23 2013
Finder: DVDRW  GA32N: SCSITask 1663.657471 CDB: Read (10), block: 0, count: 512 failed with service response = 1 (SERVICE_DELIVERY_OR_TARGET_FAILURE), status = 5 (DeliveryFailure)
Finder: Retry #1
Finder: DVDRW  GA32N: SCSITask 1678.670898 CDB: Read (10), block: 0, count: 512 failed with service response = 1 (SERVICE_DELIVERY_OR_TARGET_FAILURE), status = 5 (DeliveryFailure)
Finder: Retry #2
Finder: DVDRW  GA32N: SCSITask 1693.684570 CDB: Read (10), block: 0, count: 512 failed with service response = 1 (SERVICE_DELIVERY_OR_TARGET_FAILURE), status = 5 (DeliveryFailure)
Finder: Retry #3
Finder: DVDRW  GA32N: SCSITask 1708.698486 CDB: Read (10), block: 0, count: 512 failed with service response = 1 (SERVICE_DELIVERY_OR_TARGET_FAILURE), status = 5 (DeliveryFailure)
Finder: Giving up
Finder: Verify failed, Sat Nov  2 18:22:23 2013
Finder: Verify error: 0x80020063 Verifying the burned data failed.
```

Other things I've tried have been using a lower (minimum) write speed, deleting com.apple.finder.plist in ~/Library, updating to Mavericks, and resetting PRAM. Searching the error online turns up a whole lot of voodoo solutions involving opening and closing finder windows, which, quite frankly, make no sense, but I'm desperate enough to have tried those too.

If it's relevant, this is a Mid-2010 Mac Mini, 2.4 GHZ.

What can I do to fix this?